# Open / Edit / Save record in Django Form

Tags: python, django, post, get, django-forms

Currently i have a Django Form where i can add a new customer to the database. I also have a table showing all customers currently in this database. Now i would like to click on a customer name in the customer table to open the existing customer and have the option to edit the record and save.

Below is my current code parts, if more is needed please ask.

my navbar.html

```
<li><a href='{% url "customeradd" %}'>New Customer</a></li>
```

my urls.py

```
url(r'^customeradd/$', 'customer.views.customeradd', name='customeradd'),
```

my views.py

```
def customeradd(request): 
    form = CustomerAddForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        if form.is_valid():
            save_it = form.save(commit=False)
            save_it.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Customer added succesfully')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/customeroverview/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Customer save error, please check fields below')
    else:
        form = CustomerAddForm()


    return render_to_response("customer-add.html",
                              {"customer_add_form": form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

customeroverview.html which shows table of all customers (only three fields showing)

```
<td><a href='{% url "customeradd" %}'>{{ customer.customer_name }}</a></td>
<td>{{ customer.customer_type }}</td>
<td>{{ customer.customer_address }}</td>
```

So now i can click on the customer name in the customer table and the CustomerAddForm will open. Offcourse in the current situation empty as no arguments are given.

1. How would i pass the customer.id field as argument when clicking on the customer.customer_name hyperlink in the customeroverview.html?
2. How would i catch this customer.id in the view - how should urls.py look like?
3. When the form is opened with the existing customer.id, how should i save the current record instead of creating a new customer.id

Any help / suggestions on this situation would be very helpful in my understanding of Django GET / POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should do:

In urls.py

```
url(r'^customeradd/(?P<id>\w+)$', 'customer.views.customeradd', name='customeredit'),
url(r'^customeradd/$', 'customer.views.customeradd', name='customeradd'),
```

in your views.py:

```
def customeradd(request, id = None):
    if id:
        customer = Customer.objects.get(pk = id)
    else
        customer = None
    form = CustomerAddForm(request.POST, instance = customer)
    .....
```

in your template

```
<td>< a href='{% url "customeredit" customer.id %}' >{{ customer.customer_name }}</a></td>
<td>{{ customer.customer_type }}</td>
<td>{{ customer.customer_address }}</td>
```

Comment: Great this works for Step01 and Step02. However, when i click submit on the form it creates a new record. Any suggestion on to save the id that was opened?

Comment: Did you create a save function in CustomerAddForm ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you are talking about is called CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete).
If you are writing a simple webapp GUI (which seems so to me), an easy example can be found [here](http://rayed.com/wordpress/?p=1266) on how to implement CRUD with Django.

If, however, you are writing a REST API, things get a little more complex. [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) could be helpful then.

Comment: Thank you for the link i bookmarked it for reference